# Adding namespace to only root element using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Apologies.I have seen many similar question , but unfortunately most of them did not work for me.My Requirement is
1) I have to add namespace only for the root element using XSLT
2) I am using xsl:result-document to generate multiple XML files from single input.Root elements of all resulting doc should have namespace.

If I try the following solution , I'm getting XMLNS in all my child root tags.
If I try xsl:copy , I am getting tag from input XML which i don't want because my output tags are completely different from my input.

I/p:

```
<einfo>
    <employee>
        <eid>456</eid>
        <firstname>def</firstname>
        <lastname>y</lastname>
    </employee>
</einfo>
```

my XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <!-- Global Variables -->
    <xsl:variable name="lcletters">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="ucletters">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template match="einfo">
        <xsl:for-each select="employee">
            <xsl:variable name="docName" select="eid"/>
            <xsl:result-document href="{$docName}">
            <xsl:element name="employee" namespace="myurl">
            <xsl:call-template
                    name="processEmployees">
                <xsl:with-param name="p_firstname"
                                select="firstname"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="p_lastname"
                                select="lastname"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:element>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="processEmployees">
        <xsl:param name="p_firstname"/>
        <xsl:param name="p_lastname"/>
        <xsl:element name="firstname">
            <xsl:value-of select="$p_firstname"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="lastname">
            <xsl:value-of select="$p_lastname"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Actual output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<employee xmlns="myurl">
   <firstname xmlns="">def</firstname>
   <lastname xmlns="">y</lastname>
</employee>
```

Expected output: I need only root element i.e employee to have namespace (XMLNS).

Comment: Please post a **reproducible** example, including an input and a **complete** (preferably minimized) stylesheet - see: [mcve]. -- In general, you misunderstand how namespaces work. A default namespace is inherited. If you don't want `address` to have the overriding no-namespace declaration it has now, you must put it in the same namespace as it parent `home`. Likewise for all the other elements in the result tree.

Answer (score 0):

```
I just need name space for tag and not for all the other child tag.
```

You're confused between namespace nodes and namespace declarations. The xmlns="" is being added to the child element because in your result tree, the child element is in a different namespace from the parent. If you don't want the xmlns="", this suggests that you actually want the child to be in the same namespace as the parent. You haven't shown us the processAdd template, but the evidence is that it is creating an address in no namespace, when it should be creating an address in namespace myurl.

Comment: @micheal.hor257k ,Michael Kay , Sorry for confusing..I have posted i/p,xslt and output to explain the scenario..hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do simply:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/einfo">
    <xsl:for-each select="employee">
        <xsl:result-document href="{eid}">
            <employee xmlns="myurl">
                <firstname>
                    <xsl:value-of select="firstname" />
                </firstname>
                <lastname>
                    <xsl:value-of select="lastname" />
                </lastname>
            </employee>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Note:**

At first glance, it may seem that:

```
<firstname>
    <xsl:value-of select="firstname" />
</firstname>
```

could be shortened to:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="firstname" />
```

However, that is not true. The literal result element `<firstname>` in the stylesheet inherits the namespace of its parent `<employee xmlns="myurl">`. Writing:

```
<employee xmlns="myurl">
    <firstname>
        <xsl:value-of select="firstname" />
    </firstname>
```

is exactly the same as writing:

```
<employee xmlns="myurl">
    <firstname xmlns="myurl">
        <xsl:value-of select="firstname" />
    </firstname>
```

OTOH, if you copy the original `firstname` element from the source XML, it will be copied in its original namesepace (no-namespace in this case), and will appear in the output as:

```
<firstname xmlns="">
```